# Using Turbo C++, how I can draw graphics in C?

Tags: c++, c, turbo-c++, bgi

I've started work on computer graphics. I am using [Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C++) 3.0 as my IDE on Windows 7. The problem I am facing is that it doesn't show me any compile time error if it compiles it from Turbo C++. When I execute its EXE file, it doesn't draw any circle on the screen. It shows me the following error (*compile time*) if I compile it from a command prompt.

I've installed [DOSBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox), but it also gives me the same errors. The error I am getting is:

```
Undefined symbol _circle in module conc.c
```

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
void main()
{
    int x, y, r;
    int gd = DETECT ,gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
    setcolor(3);
    circle(250, 200, 60);
}
```

Comment: You should probably clarify one thing right away. Do you understand that the BGI (Borland Graphics Interface) programming with Turbo C++ has nothing to do with Windows graphics programming whatsoever? And unless loved one are under threat of torture, avoid Turbo C++ like the plague, opting for any of a number of free alternatives (like Visual C++ 2010/2012 Express editions).

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/455865-linker-error-undefined-symbol-_closegraph-module-graphex-cpp

Comment: Please use a compiler which was written in this century

Comment: I would like to know how you ended up using Turbo C++, so that we can find the source and end it.

Comment: @r_ahlskog May be not his fault as 70-80% engineering colleges in India still use turbo c/c++ as compiler in their labs. :D

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary and that is what we should find the source of, why use something that will put distorted ideas into peoples heads. I am not attacking him as a person but rather the institution that perpetuates this perversion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run c graphics programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513133/cannot-run-c-graphics-programs)

Comment: Don't knock Turbo C so hard... When I started programming it was awesome compared to the alternatives, the same way Doom was awesome compared to its peers.  However, if I want a FPS today, I don't boot up Doom.....

Comment: wow am I reading Turbo C++? I remember my first kiss ;P and @Ashelly I agree, Borland Compilers were years ahead of microsoft copycats!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see there isn't any fault in your C code. You're probably lacking some knowledge about your IDE ([Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C++)). Turbo C++ 3.0 on Windows 7 is really unimaginable. However, if you want to do this you should set your environment of Turbo C++. Take these simple steps:

- Go to the Menu Bar and click on Options
- Now Click on **Linker** and
- Choose libraries, Select the Graphic libraries

Since you are using it on **Windows 7**, it won't support full screen mode you should disable it. To do so, go to **Environment** and set source tracking to 'Current Window', which has a radio button swap it with 'New Window'.

---

For fullscreen mode support, you can download DOSBOX app. It can even run your old DOS applications.

For this you have to install DOSBOX and you need to mount your working directory.