# Nested IF statements vs IF-ELSE

Tags: c++, c

I'm learning C language usnig Turbo C++ compiler and just in time I encountered the two statements:

- IF (nested with many IFs)
- IF-else(not nested but continuing else,else and so on)

I was wondering if my idea is correct or not that **IF (nested with many IFs) and IF-else(not nested) are the same?** Suggestions are well appreciated.

Comment: Might want to show a code example of each so we know what you are talking about

Comment: Show the actual code you have a question about. Some are equivalent, some are not.

Comment: If _Turbo C++ 3.0_ refers to the software released in 1992 I would really encourage you to get a more modern compiler/development environment. There are several free ones around, for example [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/marsr).

Comment: Use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), consider install some Linux distributions (free).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3435105/34824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only basic logic behind that:

**Nested `if` conditions**:
IF first condition's value is true, go into the second condition.

```
if(a > 0)
{
  printf("A is greater than 0\n");
  if(a > 2) printf("A is greater than 0 and 2\n");
}
```

**`if-else` condition**:
IF first condition's value is false, go to the next:

```
if(a > 0) printf("A is greater than zero\n");
else if(a < 0) printf("A is lesser than zero\n");
else printf("A is zero\n");
```

There is one more **instruction that you should know**, `switch`:

```
switch(a)
{
  case 0: printf("A is zero\n"); break;
  case 1: printf("A is one\n"); break;
  case 5: printf("A is five\n"); break;
  default: printf("A is not 0, 1 or 5\n"); break;
}
```

Comment: "Nested if conditions" as you stated above,If the user doesn't enters number "2" after the execution of the program and we don't create else-if to change the way when condition becomes false.The program will break in the middle or what?

Comment: @JohnCounter, the program will not do any specific action for your number then. In this case, there is another instruction `switch`, I edited my post, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Nested `if` is not equivalent to `if-else`. It can be equivalent to single `if` with a combined condition, for instance:

```
if (a == 1) {
    if (b == 2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you rather mean if this:

```
if(expression){
    //code
}
else{
    if(expression){
        //code
    }
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if(expression){
    //code
}
else if(expression){
    //code
}
```

and yes it's absolutely the same. Second one is just better looking way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The `else if` blocks are in fact nested `else`’s since C and C++ don’t have any special support for “elseif” or “elif” concept (not speaking about the preprocessor directives now). It gets obvious with strict use of blocks and indentation:

```c
if(something) { doSomething(); }
else {
    if(anotherThing) { doAnotherThing(); }
    else {
        if(yetAnotherThing) { doYetAnotherThing(); }
        else
            { doSomethingElse(); }
    }
}
```

The same code written with the usual `else if` notation:

```c
if(something) { doSomething(); }
else if(anotherThing) { doAnotherThing(); }
else if(yetAnotherThing) { doYetAnotherThing(); }
else { doSomethingElse(); }
```

And as [Mateusz Kwaśniak has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466161/711006), you should prefer `switch` over `else if` when possible. However, it’s not available for string comparison, for example.

Comment: Such a complicated structure of ifs, that looks terrible, sir.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśniak Yes, it does, that’s why everyone writes just `else if`.