# Compilation error in c++ program

Tags: c++

I'm having compilation problems. I can't see where my error came from. Can, someone help me?
The goal of this code is to ingress a date and to check if it's right.

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<math.h>
   #include<cmath>
   using namespace std;

int main(){

    int d, m, a;
    cout << "entrar dia"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    cout << "entrar mes"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    cout << "entrar ano"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    if(d<1 || d>32|| m<1 || m>13 || a<1960 || a>2022) {
        cout<<"Fecha incorrecta"<<endl;
        else {

            if( (m==4 || m==6 || m==9 || m==11) && d>30){
                cout<<"Fecha incorrecta"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else {


            if((m == 2 && a % 4 = 0 && d > 28) || (m == 2 && a % 4 == 0 && d > 29)) {
                cout<< "Fecha incorrecta"<<endl;
            }
        }

        else {
                cout <<"Fecha correcta"<<endl;
        }

    }}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read the guidelines before posting. "I have an error" is not helpful. Copy-paste the full error message.

Comment: To which `if` is bound the first `else`?

Comment: (There is an *awful* lot of guidelines - start with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).)

Answer (score 2):

You should really use [nested if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466045/nested-if-statements-vs-if-else). This helps keep your conditional logic clean, unfortunately, you have else clause's out of their expected sequence. Also your final `else if` had an assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int d, m, a;
  cout << "entrar dia" << endl;
  cin >> d;
  cout << "entrar mes" << endl;
  cin >> m;
  cout << "entrar ano" << endl;
  cin >> a;
  if (d < 1 || d > 32 || m < 1 || m > 13 || a < 1960 || a > 2022)
  {
    cout << "Fecha incorrecta" << endl;
  }
  else if ((m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) && d > 30)
  {
    cout << "Fecha incorrecta" << endl;
  }
  else if ((m == 2 && a % 4 == 0 && d > 28)
      || (m == 2 && a % 4 == 0 && d > 29))
  {
      cout << "Fecha incorrecta" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
      cout << "Fecha correcta" << endl;
  }
}
```