# Linker error in Turbo C++ through Command line

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, dosbox

When using Turbo C++ normally, I can include the, say graphics library through Options -> Linker -> Settings.

But how do I do the same thing in Command Line in DOS (DOSBox)? 
When I compile using tcc, I get lots of linker errors. How do I include the Graphics Library through Command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513133/cannot-run-c-graphics-programs

Comment: Well, I do not see how it is related to my question. I can use graphics in C++, my only problem is to use it through the command line. 
However, if the point you want to make is that I am using an ancient compiler, it's well taken.

Comment: Well, I am forced to use it. That's exactly why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -L option to add path to your libs, like

```
tcc -LC:\LIB hello.cpp
```